# URL Rewrite to remove my controller's name from the url displayed

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url

I have this site

> http://cjbuilders.info/welcome/home

and all the links start with

> http://cjbuilders.info/welcome

How can I use mod_rewrite to just remove

> /welcome/

from the url? This should be an easy one, but i struggle with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about [CodeIgniter's URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)? Add this into your routes.php config file and it should work just fine:

```
$route['home'] = 'welcome/home';
```

Comment: Nice! I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, IIRC:

```
RewriteRule ^/welcome/(.*)$ /$1 [R]
```

However, guessing a bit about what's going on here, if the reason for this prefix is something like a Java app server deploying an app at a context called "welcome", then the better solution is not to rewrite the URLs but to fix the backend app server to have a null context, i.e. serve at / rather than at /welcome/.

This is because the app server will probably want to generate links to other views of its app, and will reinsert the "welcome": this becomes a pain, and means that all links on your pages will get HTTP redirects when visited (e.g. by search engines). There is no way that the proxying apache server can parse the HTML and tell when that "welcome" should be removed, so best to fix the server that's writing the links in the first place.

Comment: It's a codeigniter app. This is my first time deploying one. Would it cause an issue with codeigniter to use the rewrite rule you have written?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about codeigniter. You may as well try the rewrite rule, but I would also have a good look in the manual, on the Web, on SO, and anywhere else you can think of to see if that context/controller name can be removed from the URLs. I was very surprised how poorly documented it was for Tomcat and Jetty, given how profound the effect on the usability of URLs is, and that most (virtual) servers are only handling one application.